# python concatenate numpy arrays with the method concatenate()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to concatenate numpy arrays.
The error that I get is : ValueError: 0-d arrays can't be concatenated

The code is the following:

```
n = len(names)
#print names
print n

pairs = concatenate(array([[(j,i) for j in xrange(i)] for i in xrange(1,n)]))
```

I just don't now how to solve this. I would be great if someone could help me.

Cheers,
M

Comment: maybe you want to do `concatenate([[(j,i) for j in xrange(i)] for i in xrange(1,n)])`? the error is because `concatenate` expects a list/tuple as input, not a single array.

Comment: "The error that I get is : `ValueError: 0-d arrays can't be concatenated`". Actually that's *not* the error you get. You get an error message that starts with `Traceback` and *ends* with that line. *All* those lines are important and you *should* always post the *whole* output you get, not just the last line. The fact that you aren't able to understand what the rest means, doesn't mean that *we* can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do. So see if it is your desired output. If it is not, please comment what is your desired output.

```
>>> n = 5
>>> a = array([[(j,i) for j in xrange(i)] for i in xrange(1,n)])
>>> a
array([
       [(0, 1)],
       [(0, 2), (1, 2)],
       [(0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3)],
       [(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
      ], dtype=object)

>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.chain(*a)
>>> list(it)
[array([0, 1]),
 array([0, 2]),
 array([1, 2]),
 array([0, 3]),
 array([1, 3]),
 array([2, 3]),
 array([0, 4]),
 array([1, 4]),
 array([2, 4]),
 array([3, 4])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what you are trying to concatenate:

```
>>> a = np.array([[(j,i) for j in xrange(i)] for i in xrange(1,n)])
>>> a
array([[(0, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2)]], dtype=object)
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a[0]
[(0, 1)]
>>> a[1]
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

You already have a numpy array of an `object` dtype. If this is what you actually want (which I doubt), just remove `concatenate`. Otherwise, what is that you actually trying to achieve.